# Changing custom TextBox's background property if Text value has changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, dependency-properties, ivalueconverter

I have a custom `TextBox` control which is inheriting `System.Windows.Controls.TextBox` and implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface .

```
public partial class V3TextBox : TextBox, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

It has a custom `OriginalValue` property and is overriding base `Text` property.

The way I imagined for it to work is to bind `Text` and `OriginalValue` to two different string properties and to set its `Background` to , let's say, yellow if those two strings are not the same and back to white if they become the same again.

These are my `Text` and `PropertyChanged` properties:

```
private Binding PropertyChangedBinding = new Binding()
{
    Path = new PropertyPath("ChangedPropertyBackground")
};

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}

private string text { get; set; } = "";
public new string Text
{
    get
    {
        return text;
    }
    set
    {
        text = value;
        if (value == originalValue)
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this, BackgroundProperty);
        else
            SetBinding(BackgroundProperty, PropertyChangedBinding);
        OnPropertyChanged("Background");
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is probably with setting `DependencyProperty` for my `OriginalValue` property.

They look like this:

```
private string originalValue;
public string OriginalValue
{
    get
    {
        return (string)GetValue(TestProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        originalValue = value;
        SetValue(TestProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("OriginalValue", typeof(string),
    typeof(V3TextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(string)));

private void OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SetValue(TestProperty, e.NewValue);
}
```

Control usage in `XAML` looks like this:

```
<Ctrls:V3TextBox x:Name="txtBxDiscountNote"
    Text="{Binding EditedNote, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
    OriginalValue="{Binding OriginalNote, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

`DataContext` is set in `XAML`.

The problem is that the `OriginalValue` property is never changed, it is always `null` and the code for changing `Background` is triggered only when `Text` property is changed programmatically, not via GUI input. Would this be easier to implement with `IValueConverter`? There will be around 30 of these controls on a single form.

Comment: As a note, it makes no sense to have a "backing field" for a dependency property, like your `originalValue`. There are also mandatory naming conventions. Your DependencyProperty field should be `OriginalValueProperty`, not `TestProperty`. Besides that, you did not register the OnTextPropertyChanged callback anywhere. Please carefully read [Custom Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties).

Comment: And do you really intend to update OriginalValue whenever Text changes (as implied by the OnTextPropertyChanged method)? Does that make sense?

Comment: As another note, it also makes no sense to implemen INotifyPropertyChanged. Background is a dependency property, and hence already has change notification support.

Comment: Also, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on the Text Binding is redundant. The Text property already binds TwoWay by default. `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` is also not necessary, unless you subscribe to the Bindings's TargetUpdated event, which you apparently don't do.

Comment: `TestProperty` became `OriginalValueProperty`, thanks.

Comment: I will never change `OriginalValue` property, I will set it only once, but `XAML` is not letting me bind it to anything if it is not a `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: Then why do you have `SetValue(TestProperty, e.NewValue)` in the OnTextPropertyChanged callback (which fortunately is never called)?

Comment: I am not using 'INotifyPropertyChanged` for `Background` property, it is for changing object upon changing `Text`, but that has nothing to do with this question, sorry if it confused you.

Comment: There is `OnPropertyChanged("Background")` in the Text setter? Please edit your question with your *actual* code.

Comment: Yes, it is in the setter, you can see it also in the question.

Comment: So, I do not need to register `PropertyChangedCallback` if I won't change the `OriginalValue`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
public class V3TextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginalValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OriginalValue", typeof(string),  typeof(V3TextBox));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChangedBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ChangedBackground", typeof(Brush), typeof(V3TextBox));

    public string OriginalValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(OriginalValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(OriginalValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush ChangedBackground
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ChangedBackgroundProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChangedBackgroundProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        if (Text == OriginalValue)
        {
            ClearValue(BackgroundProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            Background = ChangedBackground;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<local:V3TextBox OriginalValue="Hello" ChangedBackground="Yellow"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my current code:

```
public partial class V3TextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OriginalValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("OriginalValue", typeof(string), typeof(V3TextBox));
    public string OriginalValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(OriginalValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(OriginalValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);

        if (Text == OriginalValue)
            SetResourceReference(BackgroundProperty, "V3CtrlDefaultBackground");
        else
            SetResourceReference(BackgroundProperty, "V3CtrlChangedBackground");
    }


    public V3TextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and I am using it like this:

```
<Ctrls:V3TextBox x:Name="txtBxLocID"
    OriginalValue="{Binding LocationID, Mode=OneTime}"
    Text="{Binding LocationID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

That means, I am binding `Text` and `OriginalValue` to the same property, but the latter has setting `Mode=OneTime`.

So `OriginalValue` is being set only once, and is maintaining its value as long as it is alive and I am able to compare it to the current `Text` value.

@Clemens I am using some of your code, so it will be marked as the right answer, just tell me if you have any more suggestions to my code? I would need to set one more property in `XAML` with your code so I am not using `DependencyProperty` for `Background` `Brush`. Maybe if there is a way to just set `Text` property in `XAML`, set it as `OriginalValue` in code for the first time and then compare it for further changes? Can the code behind be somehow aware of the fact binding is being called for the first time or something like that? It would be nice if the `XAML` could be written without `OriginalValue` property. `OriginalValue` is not seen in the `XAML` of the `V3TextBox` itself, it would also be fine to just `One-way` bind it to `Text`.

Comment: Besides that it's entirely unclear what you are doing in the OriginalValue getter, you should know that you must not call anything else than GetValue and SetValue in the getter and setter of a dependency property. That said, the SetResourceReference does't seem to make sense, too. You don't really want to access a fixed resource key from your control code, do you? Please also note that addressing another StackOverflow user by the @ notation only works in comments.

Comment: What is it that is unclear in the `OriginalValue` getter? I just assign the value of the `OriginalValueProperty` to a variable and return `Text` if former is null. It is done so because I don't want to call `GetValue()` twice.
And for the resources - Yes, I do want to change the `DynamicResource` the `TextBox` `Background` property is pointing to, is that the wrong approach?

Comment: As said, you must not call anything else than GetValue and SetValue in the getter and setter of a dependency property. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-loading-and-dependency-properties

Comment: I managed to get it to work without the check if value is `null` by changing the `Binding` order within `XAML` where the `TextBox` is being used. Instead of: `..Text="{Binding ..}" OriginalValue="{Binding ..}"..` it is now reversed. I updated the code.